# Bot spamming with invalid utf-8 characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, character-encoding

Our rails app is being slammed by a random spamming bot and they are trying to post some weird stuff.

I already tried different solutions:

- The gem [invalid_utf8_rejector](https://github.com/alext/invalid_utf8_rejector)
- The gem [rack-uri_sanitizer](https://github.com/cfabianski/rack-uri_sanitizer)
- Some custom code in our application_controller.rb file in a
  before_filter method. `before_filter :force_utf8_params`

> ```
> def force_utf8_params
>     traverse = lambda do |object, block|
>       if object.kind_of?(Hash)
>         object.each_value { |o| traverse.call(o, block) }
>       elsif object.kind_of?(Array)
>         object.each { |o| traverse.call(o, block) }
>       else
>         block.call(object)
>       end
>       object
>     end
>     force_encoding = lambda do |o|
>       return redirect_to @MYAPP_URL+"/not-found" if o.is_a?(String) && !o.valid_encoding?
>     end
>     traverse.call(params, force_encoding)
>   end
> ```

Here is the error we are getting: `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`

I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change your code a bit, the original solution for this problem uses lamda, which is appropriate, since it tries to force encode or strip some characters. But you need to redirect and proceed with execution, so you need to use proc.

```
force_encoding = proc do |o|
 redirect_to @MYAPP_URL+"/not-found" and return if o.is_a?(String) && !o.valid_encoding?
end
```